# Slim 3.1 ubuntu server error

Tags: php, ubuntu, slim

Receiving the following server error when deploying Slim 3 application to Ubuntu server.

```
Slim Application Error
The application could not run because of the following error:

Details

Type: UnexpectedValueException
Message: The stream or file "/var/www/html/api/search-
api/src/../logs/app.log" could not be opened: failed to open 
stream:Permission denied
File: /var/www/html/api/search-
api/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php
Line: 107
```

I set the permission the logs directory to be writable, but still not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logs directory in `/var/www/html/api/search-api/src/logs` is still not writable by the web server user.

Try:

```
cd var/www/html/api/search-api/src/
sudo chgrp -R www-data logs
sudo chmod -R g+rws logs
```

This assumes that your web server is running as the `www-data` user which has a group called `www-data`.